# Is ActiveRecord changing the encoding on my serialized hash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, utf-8

I have a Rails application which accepts JSON data from third-party sources, and I believe I am running up against some ActiveRecord behind-the-scenes magic which is recognizing ASCII-8BIT characters in hashes extracted from the JSON and saving them as such to my database no matter what I do.

Here is a simplified description the class ...

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :data
end
```

and of how an object is created ...

```
a = MyClass.new 
a.data = {
  "a" =>
    {
      "b" => "bb",  
      "c" => "GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\vNETSCAPE2.0\x03\x01\x00\x00!\x04\t\x00\x00\x01\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02L\x01\x00;"
    }
}
```

I believe those are ASCII-8BIT characters, so fair enough if they are saved as such (despite my attempts to UTF8 everything everywhere). But I need these characters to be UTF-8, because when I go to view them I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ("\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
    64:       <div>
    65:         <pre><%= mc.prettify %></pre>
    66:       </div>
app/models/my_class.rb:28:in `prettify'
```

where line #28 in `prettify` is:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(self.data)
```

So I sought to re-encode any string in the Hash. I built out functionality to do this (with [anonymous classes](http://metaruby.com/t/use-rubys-refinements-anywhere-with-an-anonymous-class/489) and [refinements](http://devblog.avdi.org/2015/05/20/so-whats-the-deal-with-ruby-refinements-anyway/) to `Hash`, `Array` and `String`), but no matter what, ASCII-8BIT is returned to me. In the simplest terms here is what is happening:

```
mc = MyClass.find(123)
mc.data['a']['c'].encode!(Encoding.find('UTF-8'), {invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ''})
mc.data['a']['c'].encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
mc.data['a']['c'].valid_encoding? #=> true
mc.save!
mc.reload
mc.data['a']['c'].encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT> <-- !!!!!
```

What is ActiveRecord doing to this hash when it saves it? And what can I do to store a hash permanently with all strings encoded to UTF-8 in a `serialize`d MySQL (v5.6, via the mysql2 gem) mediumtext column (using Ruby 2.2.4 and Rails 4.1.4)?

---

my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
# ...
skip-character-set-client-handshake
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server=utf8
```

Comment: I doubt ActiveRecord is doing this. I suspect your database is. What is the collation of your table/column set to?

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong. The real problem here is that you have binary data in your JSON. You really, really shouldn't, because you're going to wind up with bytes that aren't valid UTF-8. This *will* cause problems somewhere: In your database, in Ruby, or in the JSON parser. Even bytes represented by `\xNN` have to be valid UTF-8 bytes—UTF-8 is an encoding for text, not binary data. The real solution is to encode your binary data in a safe manner first using e.g. Base64. This is both common and necessary.

Comment: @Jordan collation is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: See my second comment. You aren't going to have success storing raw binary data in UTF-8 text.

Comment: @Jordan because i'm never displaying these as images (only text) I would still have decode the strings before to `JSON.pretty_generate` (and get the error) or display nonsensical base64 on screen. (Parsing the `pretty_generate` output hunting for base64 would be prohibitively expensive.) I'm more inclined to empty the offending string. There is really no way to hammer this into UTF-8?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "parsing the `pretty_generate` output"; you would do the Base64 encoding before generating the JSON. Your alternatives are to store the data in the filesystem and its path in the JSON, or in a binary BLOB in the database. The latter would be very easy to implement.

Comment: @Jordan forget about that, it's a implementation detail related to my requirements that can't be hashed out here. Why can't I save a string with the characters I see in the Rails console as a valid UTF8 string? Why is the encoding changed after I specify it? How can I route around? That is the thrust of my question.

Comment: I just noticed your `:invalid` and `:undef` options (I'm on mobile and didn't scroll to the right) and I think your question is more complex than I've given you credit for. Sorry about that. Tell me this: After you do `reload` are the *bytes* of the string the same as they are in the string after you do `encode!`?

Answer (score 3):

So, there's not really such thing as an "ASCII-8BIT" character. `ASCII-8BIT` to ruby essentially means 'no encoding at all' -- just bytes, without assuming any encoding. It's a synonym for 'BINARY'.

But if you have bytes that aren't valid UTF-8, they can't really be encoded as UTF-8. Even if the encoding on the string were UTF-8, at best you'd get lots of InvalidEncoding errors when you tried to do something to it.

What encoding the string will end up tagged as depends on a complicated dance between ActiveRecord and your database itself -- also, the database itself can sometimes actually *change* your bytes, depending on the database and how it's set up and what you're doing. We could try to debug exactly what you are doing.

But really, the answer is -- if you want it to be UTF-8, it can't have binary non-UTF8 data in it. "ASCII-8BIT" actually *is* the right encoding for binary data. What are you actually trying to do, where do those weird bytes come from and why do you want them?  In general, I'm not sure if it's legal to put arbitrary non-UTF8 bytes in JSON?  It might be legal for JSON, but it will probably cause you headaches (such as the one you're dealing with), as it depends on what exactly both rails and your underlying DB are going to do with them.

Just to get around your display error, you could have your `prettify` method use `scrub`, added in ruby 2.1.0 to eliminate bad bytes for the current encoding. `value.force_encoding("UTF-8").scrub`.  That will probably work to get rid of your error, and will do perhaps the right thing, but it would be better to figure out what the heck is really going on, why you want those weird bytes in the first place, what they are supposed to mean for what purpose.

Comment: Thanks. This is a helpful post, but I don't think it does answer the question. I think the thrust of this is: If I want to save `\x01` as any arbitrary value in my serialized hash, then display it exactly as you see it here, how can I do this? If you're interesting in tracking it down, I've added the relevant parts of my mysql configuration file.

Comment: I'm not sure you can at all. But if you want to try, the key would be making sure the serialized hash is _not_ treated as UTF-8 in the database or by Rails when retrieiving it. I am not certain how to do that. If things are coming back as ASCII-8BIT, that's _right_. You can't have arbitrary data treated as UTF8.   You can also tell AR `serialize` to serialize as either JSON or YAML, it may be that one of those works better. It's possible there are bugs in AR preventing this. Encodings are confusing to deal with. It may be possible but I would personally only use AR serialize with UTF8 data.

Comment: If your data is coming back as a string that is ASCII-8BIT encoded, and contains the bytes you want it to contain -- that's _correct_, you don't want to mess with database encodings anymore.  Then I guess your question is how you take that ASCII-8BIT encoded string, and display it in a browser as `"GIF89a\x01\x00...`?  Keep in mind that's an escaped representation of the string, not the "actual string".  I am not sure how to turn a binary string into that representation, but it's do-able (although an unusual request), but a separate question not about ActiveRecord or databases anymore.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ruby-cookbook/0596523696/ch01s05.html

Comment: Try this on output or in your `prettify` method: `binary_str.codepoints.pack("C*")`

Comment: Packing and unpacking always results in the same thing: `\x01` becomes `\u0001` and saving the record results in it being `\x01` again. Saving and keeping the `\u0001` and displaying it would be an acceptable outcome, but somehow that option is not available to me...

Comment: Okay, you have to understand the difference between the actual bytes in your string (or your database), and what is shown to you on the screen, in say a console, when you print the variable. Then what shows up in the browser is another thing entirely, but start with the first two for now. Until you understand that, you are never going to be able to debug this. When you see `"\x01"` on the screen, it does NOT mean the bytes in the string in memory were a `/` then an `x` then a `0` etc.

Comment: When you see `"\x01"` on the screen, it actually means the SAME THING as `"\u0001"` -- it's the exact same bytes in the string in memory (or in the database).  I understand that you might want one of these but not the other to display, but "Saving and keeping the \u0001 and displaying it" is kind of a nonsense phrase. Until you understand the difference between the actual bytes in the string (and database), and how they are displayed in an escaped form (in the console for instance), you are just random twiddling, and you won't get to the bottom of this. So I'd focus on understanding that.

Comment: really, I don't understand what you're trying to do or why, and I'm not sure you do either.  If there's a byte 0001 in the string in the database, it can't be displayed as an ordinary letter. Byte 0001 is not an ordinary letter. Ruby escaping uses "\x01" to represent this in some cases, and "\u0001" in others. They are both escaped representations of byte 0001.  You have binary data. You want to display it. What are your specifications for how you want to display it? Why do you care if it's "\x01" or "\u0001"? I'm not saying you shouldn't, I'm saying I don't think you understand what's up.

Comment: You're 100% correct -- I have no idea what I'm doing, and that's why I'm here. To clarify, I want one thing: to save a string to my database that `JSON.pretty_generate` can ingest and `ActionView::Template` can display. I even willing to deep-scrub these hashes to modify each string as necessary (though I don't think I should have to). Given that, how I can I transmute these strings in a reproducible way to text printable from a `ActionView::Template`?

Comment: I think some of those bytes are not legal values in JSON, so you're going to have trouble working with it in JSON tools. You can't put binary data, like a GIF file, in JSON. Sorry, what you say you want is not really well-specified. I was trying to help you understand what was going on, so you could understand your options. I don't know, good luck.